# Change "Read more" link in Wordpress 4.1 to prevent scroll/remove "more-X" hash

Tags: wordpress

I insert read more tag this way:

[image: insert read more tag]

*Continue reading* link send to `/%postname%/#more-9`, I need only `/%postname%/`.

What should I change and where? No results for "**more**" in *functions.php* (wp-incudes and theme file).

Comment: The #more-9 section shouldn't be used by the PHP - the server doesn't use the hashtag blocks in URLs - those are used by the web browser to indicate a status. Does the link work when you remove that block?

Comment: Link works in both situations.

Comment: So why is it that you want to remove the `#more-9`? It's there for a reason - you can then track user flow's later to see if they get directly to posts or get there from more links...

Comment: Yes, but I don't need it.

Comment: See the provided answer by vicvicvic.

Comment: This also stopped my navigation drop down function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is detailed in the codex under "[Prevent Page Scroll When Clicking the More Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link)", and handled by applying the filter `the_content_more_link`:

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
  $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
  return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

Add this to your theme's `functions.php`